# Regex to modify an html tag

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am trying to replace

```
<legend>my legend</legend>
```

with

```
<legend><span>my legend</span></legend>
```

Intellij/Webstorm,supports regexp match and replace.
I tried along the examples [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html), but didn't work.
Any help on a regexp to find and replace as described above is appreciated.

I use mac, so gnu command line tools also an option (sed,..)

Thanks.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  It's generally a bad idea to manipulate the DOM with regex.  Instead you should use DOM manipulation (e.g. `document.createElement` and `element.appendChild` etc.).  It looks like this webstorm doesn't prevent such javascript from being written.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use replace with the following regular expression:

```
<legend>([^<]*)</legend>
```

and replacement

```
<legend><span>$1</span></legend>
```